# M.2 SSD doesn't show in BIOS or Disk Manager

Tags: windows-10, ssd, compatibility

I purchased a Crucial M.2 SSD for my Lenovo 720 241KB IdeaCentre AIO. It's currently running with standard 1TB HDD. Lenovo states that it can be upgraded to an SSD, but it is not showing at all anywhere on the system on boot-up or in BIOS. I did clone it using Acronis via a USB 3 external enclosure which worked OK, and it shows up in My computer as drive D, but when put in the internal slot it does absolutely nothing.

Crucial says it is compatible. Lenovo states that 256GB is the maximum size SSD that can be used, but even so surely the 525 would show up somewhere. All firmware and drivers are up-to-date.

Otherwise I'm just left with an expensive external hard drive.

Comment: M2 is a form factor that can support both SATA and/or PCIe connections. It could well be that this is PCIe only. I'm assuming that you're having a SATA class SSD as those are usually found within external USB-3 enclosures.

Comment: "but even so surely the 525 would show up somewhere" - That isn't guaranteed and likely is the reason the system is being detected.

Answer (score 1):

M.2 comes in multiple variants.  You need to make sure the slot you're jamming the SSD into is the correct kind for your SSD... and make sure that the slot is indeed designed for a SSD.  They may also be suggesting that you must use a SATA SSD (2.5" form-factor) instead of M.2.  Not all "M.2" slots support SATA.

You can do quite a bit more reading here: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying